Mathematica solve with conditions on constants differ from replace
I have been trying to solve some complicated linear equations in Mathematica, with variables $y_{i}$, and constants $a, f_{j}$ where $0\leq j\leq10$. I only care about the case where $\sum_{i=1}^{10}ia^{i-1}f_{i} = 0$. With the following code, where I first solve for the general case, and then substitute this rule of $\sum_{i=1}^{10}ia^{i-1}f_{i} = 0$, it succeeds.
sol = Solve[
   eqns, {Subscript[y, -1], Subscript[y, 0], Subscript[y, 1], 
    Subscript[y, 2], Subscript[y, 3], Subscript[y, 4], Subscript[y, 
    5], Subscript[y, 6], Subscript[y, 7], Subscript[y, 8], Subscript[
    y, 9], Subscript[y, 10], Subscript[y, 11], Subscript[y, 12], 
    Subscript[y, 13], Subscript[y, 14], Subscript[y, 15], Subscript[y,
     16], Subscript[y, 17], Subscript[y, 18], Subscript[y, 19], 
    Subscript[y, 20], Subscript[y, 21], Subscript[y, 22], Subscript[y,
     23], Subscript[y, 24], Subscript[y, 25], Subscript[y, 26], 
    Subscript[y, 27], Subscript[y, 28], Subscript[y, 29], Subscript[y,
     30], Subscript[y, 31], Subscript[y, 32], Subscript[y, 33], 
    Subscript[y, 34], Subscript[y, 35], Subscript[y, 36], Subscript[y,
     37], Subscript[y, 38], Subscript[y, 39], Subscript[y, 40], 
    Subscript[y, 41], Subscript[y, 42], Subscript[y, 43], Subscript[y,
     44]}, Reals];
solFirstOrderPts = 
  sol /. Subscript[f, 1] + 2 a Subscript[f, 2] + 
     3 a^2 Subscript[f, 3] + 4 a^3 Subscript[f, 4] + 
     5 a^4 Subscript[f, 5] + 6 a^5 Subscript[f, 6] + 
     7 a^6 Subscript[f, 7] + 8 a^7 Subscript[f, 8] + 
     9 a^8 Subscript[f, 9] + 10 a^9 Subscript[f, 10] -> 0;
solFirstOrderPts = 
 Flatten[Expand[solFirstOrderPts] /. 
   Subscript[f, 1] + 2 a Subscript[f, 2] + 3 a^2 Subscript[f, 3] + 
     4 a^3 Subscript[f, 4] + 5 a^4 Subscript[f, 5] + 
     6 a^5 Subscript[f, 6] + 7 a^6 Subscript[f, 7] + 
     8 a^7 Subscript[f, 8] + 9 a^8 Subscript[f, 9] + 
     10 a^9 Subscript[f, 10] -> 0]


However, when I tried to append eqns with $\sum_{i=1}^{10}ia^{i-1}f_{10} = 0$, it results in no solution. What could cause this?


Searching on internet, it seems that one can indeed append constraints on the constants when using Solve. However, I'm not sure if I should do this. Or perhaps should I use Reduce?

The solution is the following after replace:
{Subscript[y, -1] -> 
  Subscript[f, 0] + (3 a Subscript[f, 1])/4 + (a^2 Subscript[f, 2])/
   2 + (a^3 Subscript[f, 3])/4 - (a^5 Subscript[f, 5])/4 - (
   a^6 Subscript[f, 6])/2 - (3 a^7 Subscript[f, 7])/4 - 
   a^8 Subscript[f, 8] - (5 a^9 Subscript[f, 9])/4 - (
   3 a^10 Subscript[f, 10])/2, 
 Subscript[y, 
  0] -> -(Subscript[f, 1]/(4 a)) - (a Subscript[f, 3])/4 - (
   a^2 Subscript[f, 4])/2 - (3 a^3 Subscript[f, 5])/4 - 
   a^4 Subscript[f, 6] - (5 a^5 Subscript[f, 7])/4 - (
   3 a^6 Subscript[f, 8])/2 - (7 a^7 Subscript[f, 9])/4 - 
   2 a^8 Subscript[f, 10], 
 Subscript[y, 1] -> 
  Subscript[f, 3]/2 + (a Subscript[f, 4])/2 + (a^2 Subscript[f, 5])/
   2 + (a^3 Subscript[f, 6])/2 + (a^4 Subscript[f, 7])/2 + (
   a^5 Subscript[f, 8])/2 + (a^6 Subscript[f, 9])/2 + (
   a^7 Subscript[f, 10])/2, 
 Subscript[y, 2] -> 
  Subscript[f, 4]/2 + (a Subscript[f, 5])/2 + (a^2 Subscript[f, 6])/
   2 + (a^3 Subscript[f, 7])/2 + (a^4 Subscript[f, 8])/2 + (
   a^5 Subscript[f, 9])/2 + (a^6 Subscript[f, 10])/2, 
 Subscript[y, 3] -> 0, 
 Subscript[y, 4] -> 
  Subscript[f, 5]/2 + (a Subscript[f, 6])/2 + (a^2 Subscript[f, 7])/
   2 + (a^3 Subscript[f, 8])/2 + (a^4 Subscript[f, 9])/2 + (
   a^5 Subscript[f, 10])/2, Subscript[y, 5] -> 0, 
 Subscript[y, 6] -> 
  Subscript[f, 6]/2 + (a Subscript[f, 7])/2 + (a^2 Subscript[f, 8])/
   2 + (a^3 Subscript[f, 9])/2 + (a^4 Subscript[f, 10])/2, 
 Subscript[y, 7] -> 0, Subscript[y, 8] -> 0, 
 Subscript[y, 9] -> 
  Subscript[f, 7]/2 + (a Subscript[f, 8])/2 + (a^2 Subscript[f, 9])/
   2 + (a^3 Subscript[f, 10])/2, Subscript[y, 10] -> 0, 
 Subscript[y, 11] -> 0, 
 Subscript[y, 12] -> 
  Subscript[f, 8]/2 + (a Subscript[f, 9])/2 + (a^2 Subscript[f, 10])/
   2, Subscript[y, 13] -> 0, Subscript[y, 14] -> 0, 
 Subscript[y, 15] -> 0, 
 Subscript[y, 16] -> Subscript[f, 9]/2 + (a Subscript[f, 10])/2, 
 Subscript[y, 17] -> 0, Subscript[y, 18] -> 0, Subscript[y, 19] -> 0, 
 Subscript[y, 20] -> Subscript[f, 10]/2, Subscript[y, 21] -> 0, 
 Subscript[y, 22] -> 0, Subscript[y, 23] -> 0, Subscript[y, 24] -> 0, 
 Subscript[y, 25] -> 0, Subscript[y, 26] -> 0, Subscript[y, 27] -> 0, 
 Subscript[y, 28] -> 0, Subscript[y, 29] -> 0, Subscript[y, 30] -> 0, 
 Subscript[y, 31] -> 0, Subscript[y, 32] -> 0, Subscript[y, 33] -> 0, 
 Subscript[y, 34] -> 0, Subscript[y, 35] -> 0, Subscript[y, 36] -> 0, 
 Subscript[y, 37] -> 0, Subscript[y, 38] -> 0, Subscript[y, 39] -> 0, 
 Subscript[y, 40] -> 0, Subscript[y, 41] -> 0, Subscript[y, 42] -> 0, 
 Subscript[y, 43] -> 0, Subscript[y, 44] -> 0}


Here is the equation I want to solve: And the code below is
(*Set up the equation Tx=Cx*)
exceptions = {-1, 0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 9, 12, 16, 20, 42};
zeroConditions = 
  Table[If[! MemberQ[exceptions, i], Subscript[y, i] == 0, 
    Nothing], {i, -1, 44}];
lhs = Flatten[Subscript[T, 2] . x];
rhs = Flatten[cVar . x];
eqns = Thread[lhs == rhs];
eqns = Join[eqns, 
   zeroConditions, {Subscript[f, 1] + 2 a Subscript[f, 2] + 
      3 a^2 Subscript[f, 3] + 4 a^3 Subscript[f, 4] + 
      5 a^4 Subscript[f, 5] + 6 a^5 Subscript[f, 6] + 
      7 a^6 Subscript[f, 7] + 8 a^7 Subscript[f, 8] + 
      9 a^8 Subscript[f, 9] + 10 a^9 Subscript[f, 10] == 0}];
sol = Solve[
  eqns, {Subscript[y, -1], Subscript[y, 0], Subscript[y, 1], 
   Subscript[y, 2], Subscript[y, 3], Subscript[y, 4], Subscript[y, 5],
    Subscript[y, 6], Subscript[y, 7], Subscript[y, 8], Subscript[y, 
   9], Subscript[y, 10], Subscript[y, 11], Subscript[y, 12], 
   Subscript[y, 13], Subscript[y, 14], Subscript[y, 15], Subscript[y, 
   16], Subscript[y, 17], Subscript[y, 18], Subscript[y, 19], 
   Subscript[y, 20], Subscript[y, 21], Subscript[y, 22], Subscript[y, 
   23], Subscript[y, 24], Subscript[y, 25], Subscript[y, 26], 
   Subscript[y, 27], Subscript[y, 28], Subscript[y, 29], Subscript[y, 
   30], Subscript[y, 31], Subscript[y, 32], Subscript[y, 33], 
   Subscript[y, 34], Subscript[y, 35], Subscript[y, 36], Subscript[y, 
   37], Subscript[y, 38], Subscript[y, 39], Subscript[y, 40], 
   Subscript[y, 41], Subscript[y, 42], Subscript[y, 43], Subscript[y, 
   44]}, Reals]
solFirstOrderPts = 
  sol /. Subscript[f, 1] + 2 a Subscript[f, 2] + 
     3 a^2 Subscript[f, 3] + 4 a^3 Subscript[f, 4] + 
     5 a^4 Subscript[f, 5] + 6 a^5 Subscript[f, 6] + 
     7 a^6 Subscript[f, 7] + 8 a^7 Subscript[f, 8] + 
     9 a^8 Subscript[f, 9] + 10 a^9 Subscript[f, 10] -> 0;
solFirstOrderPts = 
 Flatten[Expand[solFirstOrderPts] /. 
   Subscript[f, 1] + 2 a Subscript[f, 2] + 3 a^2 Subscript[f, 3] + 
     4 a^3 Subscript[f, 4] + 5 a^4 Subscript[f, 5] + 
     6 a^5 Subscript[f, 6] + 7 a^6 Subscript[f, 7] + 
     8 a^7 Subscript[f, 8] + 9 a^8 Subscript[f, 9] + 
     10 a^9 Subscript[f, 10] -> 0]

Whether zeroConditions is included or not, when I append the condition (as in the code above):
{Subscript[f, 1] + 2 a Subscript[f, 2] + 
      3 a^2 Subscript[f, 3] + 4 a^3 Subscript[f, 4] + 
      5 a^4 Subscript[f, 5] + 6 a^5 Subscript[f, 6] + 
      7 a^6 Subscript[f, 7] + 8 a^7 Subscript[f, 8] + 
      9 a^8 Subscript[f, 9] + 10 a^9 Subscript[f, 10] == 0}

The first solve results in an empty solution

(1) I'm pretty sure that the key to the answer lies in the code for eqn. Is there a way to include it? (2) Which of the three ways for Solve[] to fail to solve a system (that occur to me) does Solve[] return? (3) Maybe LinearSolve[] gives a better answer.

@MichaelE2 I've attached the eqn above. Solve returns {} when I include the condition

I think the definitions of cVar and x are missing.
